# how to access elements in popup window , cant access popup windows element (selenium Java )

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

so here is the senario, whenever I click add to bag there is a popup window with a button go-to bag, but somehow i am not able to access any element from this popup window I have tried locators but not able to access any of it , I am sharing my code and console error message, i have tried list elements also but it also didn't worked.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("//a[normalize-space()='Single Arrow Slim Fit Sweatshirt in Cotton Blend']")).click();
            
            //  List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className(".CartItem.MiniCartPopup.is-separate"));  
            //List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='MiniCart-items']/div")); 
            // System.out.println(elements.size()); 
            //System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='MiniCart-items']/div")).size());
            
            
            String kk = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[aria-label='icon-bag'] span")).getText();
            System.out.println("the items on products are"+ kk);
            String comp=driver.findElement(By.linkText("Single Arrow Slim Fit Sweatshirt in Cotton Blend")).getText();
           
            System.out.println("the selected items have text" +comp);
```

This is code of popup window which is not accessible during the normal window, but once it hovered then only its code can be inspected

```
 <div class="CartItem-content"><div class="CartItem-thumbAndBadge">
<a class="CartItem-pdpLink" href="/shop-off-white-single-arrow-slim-fit-sweatshirt-in-cotton-blend-for-men-215022969_22.html">
<img src="//ounass-prod1.atgcdn.ae/small_light(p=thmb,ch=158,cc=fafafa,of=webp)/pub/media/catalog/product/2/1/215022969_orange_in.jpg?1654148030.1771" alt="Single Arrow Slim Fit Sweatshirt in Cotton Blend">
</a>
</div>
<div class="CartItem-info"><h3 class="CartItem-brand"><a href="/shop-off-white-single-arrow-slim-fit-sweatshirt-in-cotton-blend-for-men-215022969_22.html">Off-White</a>
</h3>
<h4 class="CartItem-name"><a href="/shop-off-white-single-arrow-slim-fit-sweatshirt-in-cotton-blend-for-men-215022969_22.html">Single Arrow Slim Fit Sweatshirt in Cotton Blend</a></h4><div class="CartItem-attribute">
<span class="CartItem-attributeName">Colour</span>
<span class="CartItem-attributeValue">Orange</span></div>
<div class="CartItem-attribute"><span class="CartItem-attributeName">Size</span>
<span class="CartItem-attributeValue">S</span>
</div>
<div class="CartItem-attribute"><span class="CartItem-attributeName">Qty</span>
<span class="CartItem-attributeValue">1</span></div>
<div class="CartItem-badge"></div>
<div class="MessageShort display-flexAIC mt10-md" style="color: rgb(203, 32, 45);">
<svg width="12" height="12" viewBox="0 0 26 26" class="svg"><g stroke="#cb202d" class="svg-stroke"><circle cx="13" cy="13" r="12.5">
</circle>
<path d="M13 6.5V13l3 3"></path></g></svg>
<span class="ml5">Low in stock: only 1 left.</span>
</div>
<div class="CartItem-actionLinks"></div></div>
<div class="CartItem-priceAndRemove mlAuto">
<div class="CartItem-oldPrice">2,500 AED</div><div class="CartItem-currentPrice is-discounted">1,625 AED</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason its not able to access popup window is because after clicking on `Add To Bag` button the `popup window` takes some time to display.

You can wait for the `popup` to display or `hover` on the bag icon

Also on the line `By.xpath("//*[@id='MiniCart-items']/div` we are using the `id property` for `MiniCart-items` but is the classname not the id

Your solution would look like

```
// Click on Add To Bag
driver.findElement(By.className("AddToBag")).click();
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);;
// Using wait to ensure the popup is displayed before searching for details from the popup
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='Popup-content']")));
// Alternatively can hover on the bag icon to display the popup content
Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
actions.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='Popup-iconLink has-product']"))).perform();
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='CartItem MiniCartPopup is-separate']"));
System.out.println(elements.size());
System.out.println(driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='MiniCart-items']/div")).size());
// Click on GO To Bag
driver.findElement(By.className("CartTotal-viewBag")).click();
```

Comment: it worked awesomely , its just as i am doing automation is it possible that i don't hover on the bag but instead, it should be itself, what would be the scenario then

Comment: HI @ZamirSultan if we don't want to hover on the bag then after we click on `Add To Bag` the popup appears but it takes some time to appear you can use the wait section that i have added for that  and remove the section to hover on the bag i.e

Comment: WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);;
// Using wait to ensure the popup is displayed before searching for details from the popup
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='Popup-content']")));

Comment: Can you check with that approach i.e `wait one`

Comment: hi yes i did tried and it is working perfectly thanx alot , and if i want to access the text in this statement , what should be the code <h4 class="CartItem-name"><a href="/shop-off-white-single-arrow-slim-fit-sweatshirt-in-cotton-blend-for-men-215022969_22.html">Single Arrow Slim Fit Sweatshirt in Cotton Blend</a></h4><div class="CartItem-attribute">

Comment: i tried this approch ,  .//h4[@class="CartItem-name"].gettext()

Comment: Hi @ZamirSultan the text you are  trying to access is part of the anchor tag so in order to get text you need to access the `anchor tag` i.e `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//h4[@class="CartItem-name"]/a")).getText();`

Comment: hi i have approved it , i have tried this code to access size of the shirt but it is not working 
 String Sizes=driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.CartItem-attribute.CartItem-attributeValue")).getText(); , also used this one as well 
 String Sizes=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='CartItem-attributeValue']/span")).getText(); , none of them are working

Comment: Hi @ZamirSultan thanks,. ALso for accessing size the `xpath` has to be specific since we have multiple element with class `CartItem-attributeValue` we can use the label property to access it i.e `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='CartItem-attributeName'  and contains(text(), 'Size')]/following-sibling::span")).getText()`

Comment: Hi @DarshanShah , thanx alot i get it , one thing i have searched alot online and that is wat if there are 2 div with same class names and then inside each on of them they are their different attribute like size , color etc . here is the code once i m in second div i can access its elements .
<div class="CartItem MiniCartPopup is-separate" xpath="1"></div>
<div class="CartItem MiniCartPopup is-separate"></div>
<div class="CartItem MiniCartPopup is-separate"></div> , now how to access any of these and then access elements inside them

Comment: HI @ZamirSultan the above case you mention `where multiple div` with same `class name` we need to locate the element base on `inner attribute i.e size ,color, qty` e.g   `color` - `//span[@class='CartItem-attributeName'  and contains(text(), 'Colour')]/following-sibling::span`  for colour , similarly for size `//span[@class='CartItem-attributeName'  and contains(text(), 'Size')]/following-sibling::span`

Comment: You can refer xpath axes documents to  locate an element based on (or relative ) to some other element  https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/xpath-axes-tutorial/

Comment: String Sizes=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='CartItem-attribute']/span[2]")).getText(); , the problem is both div have same div inside them , its just they have different size and color , but in the first place suppose i want to go into 2nd div then how can i select 2nd div and see inside  what is the size and color